# Cannot start dev server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

With this command

```
dev_appserver.py .
```

I'm trying to deploy to local server however it is giving me an error:

```
INFO     2015-12-18 17:09:57,667 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:51776
INFO     2015-12-18 17:09:57,678 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-12-18 17:09:57,681 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\_python_runtime.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\_python_runtime.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime.py", line 175, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime.py", line 155, in main
    sandbox.enable_sandbox(config)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 170, in enable_sandbox
    _install_fake_file(config, python_lib_paths, path_override_hook)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 252, in _install_fake_file
    stubs.FakeFile.set_skip_files(config.skip_files)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\stubs.py", line 178, in set_skip_files
    FakeFile._skip_files = re.compile(skip_files)
  File "C:\python27\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\python27\lib\re.py", line 245, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

I have tried to reinstall Google App Engine SDK but still no luck. Any idea on why it doesn't work? It worked before until I listened to it and updated the Cloud SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the dev_appserver bundled with gcloud, which sometimes is not fully up to date. To bypass the problem, follow the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads?hl=en to download and install GoogleAppEngine-1.9.30.msi -- and make sure you use *that* dev_appserver. Also, please open a bug report about the gcloud-bundled dev_appserver at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads?hl=en (with the same information you've posted here plus your exact OS and results of `gcloud components list` to pin-point exactly what components have a bug), thanks.

(In theory the error you observe could be explained by an erroneous `skip_files` stanza in your app.yaml, but if that was the case then it shouldn't have worked previously with different dev_appserver releases).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! When you mentioned `skip_files` in app.yaml I immediately went for a quick check, and apparently the mistake is on my side - for some reason a character was deleted by accident, where a dot in front of an asterisk is missing.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 oh good -- glad to have been of help! The skip_files hint is in the traceback you showed us, which at the end (close to root cause of errors) is doing a `re.compile(skip_files)`.